# Lottie Player got deleted immediately after page load

Tags: javascript, wordpress, elementor, lottie

Folks my Lottie player HTML element is got deleted every time the page loads. The website is on WordPress and the Lottie player code is infused through a custom plugin. It is working fine on this website strucurecore.net but on this site, blueprintee.com animation just shows and got deleted. Even if I try to inspect the code It is not there where it has to be.
Just see this Screenshot:[image]

The code which is deleted is:

```
<lottie-player src="'.plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'/assets/fetching.json" background="transparent"  speed="1"  style="width: 300px; height: 300px; margin:auto;z-index:99;position:relative;margin-bottom: -150px;" loop autoplay></lottie-player>
```

The Elementor Pro plugin is installed on the site.
So any hack to avoid the deletion of the Lottie player element?

Thanks.

Comment: In debugging I have also checked that the animation is working on the canvas and default template however it is not working on the full-width template.